# Why is Elasticsearch/Opensearch query returning everything?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, aws-elasticsearch, opensearch

I'm using AWS's OpenSearch, and I'm having trouble getting any queries or filters to only return matching results.

To test, I'm using sample ecommerce data that includes the field "customer_gender" that's one of "MALE" or FEMALE." I'm trying to use the following query:

```json
GET /kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search

{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query" : "FEMALE"
      "fields": ["customer_gender"]
    }
  }
}
```

But all the results with "MALE" are still showing up. I've tried this as a `POST` request instead of a `GET` request, I've tried lowercasing, and I've tried using term queries and fulltext queries (like `match`) and I'm getting the same results every time. Is there some way I'm formatting these queries wrong? I've scoured through the documentation and I haven't been able to find any clues that have had a difference.

Here are some JSON examples of other types of queries I've tried:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "customer_gender": "FEMALE"
    }
  }
}

{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "customer_gender": {
        "value": "FEMALE"
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "customer_gender": "FEMALE"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an example of a `_source` for query objects:

```
        {
          "category" : [
            "Men's Clothing"
          ],
          "currency" : "EUR",
          "customer_first_name" : "Eddie",
          "customer_full_name" : "Eddie Underwood",
          "customer_gender" : "MALE",
          "customer_id" : 38,
          "customer_last_name" : "Underwood",
          "customer_phone" : "",
          "day_of_week" : "Monday",
          "day_of_week_i" : 0,
          "email" : "eddie@underwood-family.zzz",
          "manufacturer" : [
            "Elitelligence",
            "Oceanavigations"
          ],
          "order_date" : "2021-11-29T09:28:48+00:00",
          "order_id" : 584677,
          "products" : [
            {
              "base_price" : 11.99,
              "discount_percentage" : 0,
              "quantity" : 1,
              "manufacturer" : "Elitelligence",
              "tax_amount" : 0,
              "product_id" : 6283,
              "category" : "Men's Clothing",
              "sku" : "ZO0549605496",
              "taxless_price" : 11.99,
              "unit_discount_amount" : 0,
              "min_price" : 6.35,
              "_id" : "sold_product_584677_6283",
              "discount_amount" : 0,
              "created_on" : "2016-12-26T09:28:48+00:00",
              "product_name" : "Basic T-shirt - dark blue/white",
              "price" : 11.99,
              "taxful_price" : 11.99,
              "base_unit_price" : 11.99
            },
            {
              "base_price" : 24.99,
              "discount_percentage" : 0,
              "quantity" : 1,
              "manufacturer" : "Oceanavigations",
              "tax_amount" : 0,
              "product_id" : 19400,
              "category" : "Men's Clothing",
              "sku" : "ZO0299602996",
              "taxless_price" : 24.99,
              "unit_discount_amount" : 0,
              "min_price" : 11.75,
              "_id" : "sold_product_584677_19400",
              "discount_amount" : 0,
              "created_on" : "2016-12-26T09:28:48+00:00",
              "product_name" : "Sweatshirt - grey multicolor",
              "price" : 24.99,
              "taxful_price" : 24.99,
              "base_unit_price" : 24.99
            }
          ],
          "sku" : [
            "ZO0549605496",
            "ZO0299602996"
          ],
          "taxful_total_price" : 36.98,
          "taxless_total_price" : 36.98,
          "total_quantity" : 2,
          "total_unique_products" : 2,
          "type" : "order",
          "user" : "eddie",
          "geoip" : {
            "country_iso_code" : "EG",
            "location" : {
              "lon" : 31.3,
              "lat" : 30.1
            },
            "region_name" : "Cairo Governorate",
            "continent_name" : "Africa",
            "city_name" : "Cairo"
          },
          "event" : {
            "dataset" : "sample_ecommerce"
          }
        }
```

EDIT: The Kibana dashboards/explore pages are all querying just fine, as a note, but when I copy-paste the same queries to the console, it's still not working there

Comment: That's weird, your `match` queries should work. Do you use custom mappings?

Comment: if you are using `multi_match` then shouldn't it be `"query" : "FEMALE"` rather than `"customer_gender" : "FEMALE"` given that you've indicated which fields to query in `"fields": ["customer_gender"]`?

Comment: @ilvar I'm not aware of any, but I'm also not the one who set up the cluster. Do you know where I could look to figure that out?

Comment: @jarmod ah rats, you're absolutely correct -- I'll update the question; changing it to that produces the same results, though

Comment: To get mappings, invoke `GET /myindex/_mapping` or `GET /*/_mapping`.

Comment: The mapping for this field is `"customer_gender": { "type": "keyword" }`

Comment: Can you test: `"query" : {"term" : {"customer_gender.keyword" : "FEMALE"}}`. Not saying this is ideal because using a term query for text is discouraged afaik.

Comment: @jarmond That has the same result, unfortunately, still returning results with both `MALE` and `FEMALE`

Comment: I think you are using kibana dev tools. It is probably beacuse you have an empty line between the `GET /kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search` line and your query. If you remove the line it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have an empty line between GET and the query, so there's no query being sent, hence it's equivalent to a `match_all` query:

```
GET /kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search
                         <--- remove this empty line
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query" : "FEMALE"
      "fields": ["customer_gender"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup, this was it! I was also making API calls jusdt a little bit incorrectly when I was trying to do it externally and the separate issues wound up causing the same result. Thank you!